# Create wall timer using callback with parameters - ROS2, C++

Tags: ros, ros2, timer, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have two image msg synchronized as follows:

```
 message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image>  sync(image_1, image_2, 10);
 sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
```

It works until here. Now I'd want to define an interval between triggers of the callback using **create_wall_timer**.  I tried:

```
 node->create_wall_timer(500ms, boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
```

But I'm getting errors when using it

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::Node::create_wall_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const std::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >)
```

What would be the proper way to use it? Thanks in advance.

obs: I tried with a callback without parameters `node->create_wall_timer(500ms, &callback_test)` and it works fine...

obs: alternatives to **create_wall_timer** are also welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375561/create-wall-timer-using-callback-with-parameters---ros2,-c++/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 uses std for bind and most other things that used to use Boost in ROS1. So that line would work as you expect with `std::bind`.

A practical example in ROS2 can be seen in Nav2's lifecycle manager https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/30b405c58e6d53ba8c96381416bc4679d35a1483/nav2_lifecycle_manager/src/lifecycle_manager.cpp#L318-L320

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your question it seems that you expect that `create_wall_timer` can be used to specify how often the `TimeSynchronizer` calls its callback, but that's not the case. The synchronizer will just call its callback as soon as it has two synchronized messages to pass on.

`create_wall_timer` sets a completely unrelated timer that just calls its callback after the set time. It doesn't know about any topics or events that you may have used the same callback function for. And it does not have any of such information to pass to its callback, so it expects the callback function that you give to take 0 arguments. You pass it one that takes 2, which causes the error: 'there is no matching version of `create_wall_timer` that can deal with a callback that takes 2 arguments'.

That's why your test with `callback_test` does work, it takes no arguments, which is what the timer expects.

Side notes:

- When you only use placeholders, you shouldn't need `bind`, you should be able to just use `sync.registerCallback(&callback)`. `bind` is used if you want to use a class method as callback and you have to bind it to `this`.
- You can also use lambda's instead of either `boost::bind` or `std::bind`, which I personally like better so you don't have to use function pointers or library methods:

  ```
    node->create_wall_timer(500ms, []() -> void { callback(); });
  ```

  Again here wrapping into a lambda is not strictly necessary and you could just use `&callback`; you could instead put the logic inside `capture()` directly into the lambda function, or capture any local variables that can be used at the time the callback is called. For instance as alternative to binding `this` if `callback` is a method on your node class:

  ```
    node->create_wall_timer(500ms, [this]() -> void { callback(); });
  ```

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2021-09-23**:
Hi @sgvandijk . I just stumbled upon this answer and I have two little questions about it: 1. I didn't understand the difference between the two lambda examples you gave. What does it change to capture or not capture `this`? 2. You are saying it's not necessary to wrap in a lamba. If I don't wrap, compiler complains: "vehicle.cpp:21:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'create_wall_timer'
node_impl.hpp:109:7: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with DurationRepT = long, DurationT = std::ratio<1, 1000>, CallbackT = void (Vehicle::*)()]". Am I doing something wrong or did they change something?

**Comment by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) on 2021-09-24**:
The difference is whether the callback is a free function or a class method. In OP's question it appears that `callback` is a free function, i.e. you can just call it as `callback()` and not as `this->callback()`. In your case I guess your callback is a member function, so you could call it as `this->callback()`, and as `callback()` because C++ allows you to omit `this->` if `this` is in scope.

So that brings us to the difference between the lambdas: if your `callback()` is a class method on your node, `this` needs to be in scope to be able to call it, so it needs to be captured. Basically any time you use a method (or other member) of the current class you're in, you need `[this]`.

Secondly, `create_wall_timer` expects a callable more akin to a free function, which is why passing it a method as I think you do does not work. To achieve this you *do* have to wrap the method in a function with `this` already baked in, which is what `bind` or the lambda does.